# Implicit conversion from a struct

Tags: c++, struct, casting, variant

This is my struct which uses implicit casting on creating variable.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <variant>

using namespace std;
using val = variant<int, string, double, bool, long, long long, long double>;

struct value
{
    val innerVal;
    value():innerVal(""){}
    value(const val &c) : innerVal(c) {}

    template <typename T>
    operator T()
    {
          return get<T>(innerVal);
    }

    template <typename V>
    value &operator=(const V &t)
    {
        innerVal = t;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

This is how I am using it when I construct a variable it works fine but when I assigned an already created variable to `value` struct it gives error.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    value h;
    h = "String";
    string m = h;// Here works fine
     string b = "different";
     b = h;//Here it gives error 
}
```

Compiler error

```
use of overloaded operator '=' is 
ambiguous (with operand types 
'std::__ndk1::string' (aka 
'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, 
allocator<char> >') and 'value')

        b = h;
```

I want to implicitly construct the variable without encountering this error can someone explain how to resolve this issue.

Comment: *"which uses implicit casting..."* There's no such thing as *"implicit casting"*. The correct term is *"implicit conversion"*.

Comment: `value h = "String";` won't compile. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dPWP9a4qv)

Comment: Trust me implicit conversions can really bite in (big) code bases, so stay away from them. What actual problem do you want to solve? If it is just to avoid some explicit type casting (numbers characters you have to type)... don't do it and take the little pain of a little effort right now.

Comment: The difference is that, in `string m = h;` there is no *assignment*, just a call to the `std::string` constructor (the `=` is an initialisation, here, rather than an assignment). In the second case, you are *actually* using an assignment.

Comment: Also, what compiler are you using? Mine (MSVC, with Standard set to C++17) doesn't like `value h = "String";` but will accept `value h{ "String" };`

Comment: @AdrianMole All three compilers reject `value h = "String"; `.[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dPWP9a4qv)

Comment: @AdrianMole Haha, if there is, it will be at fault, right? Since `value h = "String;"` is ill-formed but `value h{"String"};"` is not.

Comment: @user12002570 I fixed the type in question first I constructed the `h` then assign it to the `"String"` check the edited question.

Comment: @MakeMutistico Yes, I saw the change/update.

Comment: the main problem is that `std::string`  got overloads of constructor and assignment which do not play well with implcit conversion, note that `"String"` also got type of `const char[7]`, the rest is result of conversion. That's why standard library got  `const char*` overloads all over the place.

Comment: The assignment `b = h;` is ambiguous.  The compiler doesn't know how you want to resolve the several different code paths.  Tell the compiler what you want it to do by changing your code appropriately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assignment `b = h` is ambiguous, because `std::string` has different `operator=`. Because you have a templated conversion operator your compile does not know which overloaded `operator=` of `std::string` to take.

You can constrain the types of conversions allowed from `value` to allow only implicit conversions to one of the member `variant`s type.  The following struct will provide a boolean telling us, whether type `T` is contained in `Type`'s template parameters, using a  fold expression:

```
template<typename, typename>
struct has_template_param;

template<typename T, template<typename ...> typename Type, typename ...Ts>
struct has_template_param<T, Type<Ts...>> {
    static constexpr bool value = (... || std::is_same_v<T, Ts>);
};
```

Then the templated conversion operator can be constrained with SFINAE:

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<has_template_param<T, val>::value>>
operator T() {
    return std::get<T>(innerVal);
}
```

Using C++20 concepts, it can be done more conveniently via

```
template<typename T, typename Type>
concept has_param = has_template_param<T, Type>::value;
```

and

```
template<has_param<val> T>
operator T() {
    return std::get<T>(innerVal);
}
```

[See demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PKK61sfEE)

Comment: There are case where concept approach wouldn't work (i.e. target type may accepting two different matching types) but for `string` it works.

Answer (score 3):

`std::variant` desinged the way it is for reason, and one of the reasons is te problem you stumbled upon. Stored types may have overloaded copy and initialization oeprations.

This version of value is would work, although it still have some flaws and limitations of `std::variant`:

```
#include <string>
#include <variant>

using val = std::variant<int, std::string, double, bool, long, long long, long double>;

struct value
{
    val innerVal;

    value():innerVal(""){}

    // To make value copyable and movable
    value(const value&) = default;
    value(value&&) = default;

    // this would handle assignments.
    value &operator=(const value&)  = default;
    value &operator=(value&&)  = default;

    // to allow initialization in assignment form we must mimic std::variant, 
    // value(const val&) would not be enough
    template <typename V> value(V&& v):innerVal(v){}

    template <typename T>
    operator T()
    {
          return get<T>(innerVal);
    }

    // we don't need generic a operator= for every type, but we can have
    // overloads
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    value v1 = 3;
    value v2 = "String";
    value v3;
    
    v3 = "Another String";
    // std::string s1 = v1; // here you'll get exception, do you want rectify that?
    std::string s2 = v2;    // Here works fine
    s2 = std::string(v2);   // std::string is at fault here
    v1 = 42;
    v2 = v3;                // now works fine
    
}
```